Do we always use weak self and always need to use guard let self inside any closure?
The close or block is commonly used on an async process, but I saw many people doing this:
final class ViewController {
    private func bind() {
        self.viewModel.loadData { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return } 
            self.doSomething()
        }
    }
}

I feel it is not neccessary, because guard let self provide a strong reference inside a block to a weak reference outside block, it ensures that if block captures the weak self before deallocate, the code inside block still can execute.
However, if you want to skip the code inside block if self is deallocated, you can just ignore guard let self like this:
self.viewModel.loadData { [weak self in
    self?.doSomething()
}

Some people also do this:
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    guard let self else { return }
    self.updateUI()
}

Based on the fact that DispatchQueue.main is not strong hold to any of the object, event we ignore the [weak self], it will never be a reference cycle, simply do this will work without issue:
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.updateUI()
}

What you guys think about

do we need to always use guard let self else { return } inside closure?
do we need to use [weak self] in a DispatchQueue.main?


The guard let self ... construct is often used so that self doesn't have to be continually unwrapped. If, as in your case, you in,y had a single statement in the closure, you could just choose to unwrap self.

final class ViewController {
    private func bind() {
        self.viewModel.loadData { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return } 
            self.doSomething()
        }
    }
}

First, you are correct that in many cases the [weak self] here is not really necessary, but not for the reason you give:

I feel it is not neccessary, because guard let self provide a strong reference inside a block to a weak reference outside block, it ensures that if block captures the weak self before deallocate, the code inside block still can execute.

That is not what is happening. This closure does not itself hold a strong reference to self, so self is free to deallocate and when this closure is executed, the guard let self will fail and return.
The reason it is often not needed is that loadData, if written correctly, likely does not create a reference cycle. The reason for weak references is to break reference cycles where viewModel holds onto self via the reference, and self holds onto viewModel. If that is true, then self will never be released and will leak.
But a method like loadData should generally "do async thing, call completion handler, and release completion handler." And if it does that, then there is only a reference cycle for the duration of loadData, and that generally is desirable.
But there are many cases where permanent cycles do exist and must be broken with a weak reference, so this pattern is extremely common.
The order of operation looks like this:
    self.viewModel.loadData { [weak self] in ... }

A closure is created which holds a weak reference to self. That closure is passed to loadData().
We do not know what loadData() does with that closure. But it is a good bet that at some point in the future it calls it, probably a single time. And when it does, the next operation is:
        guard let self else { return } 

This is syntactic sugar for:
        guard let `self` = self else { return } 

This checks if the weak reference to self is nil. If so, then it returns. If not, it creates a new (shadow) variable called self that is a strong reference.
As long as this shadow self strong reference is in scope, the ViewController cannot deallocate.
In this specific case, using the guard is identical to using self?.doSomething(). But the guard scales much better and is generally preferred. It's definitely preferred if the closure is more than one line. Consider this:
    self.viewModel.loadData { [weak self] in
        self?.doSomething()
        print("RUNNING")
        self?.doSomethingElse()
    }

This does the following:

If self currently exists, take a strong reference and call doSomething().
Drop the strong reference to self.
Print "RUNNING" (whether self exists or not)
If self currently exists, take a strong reference and call doSomethingElse().
Drop the strong reference to self.

This means that between steps 2 and 4, self can deallocate, meaning that some operations may run and some may not. This is very rarely what you want. You either want the whole block to run or nothing. The guard let self else { return } incantation is a convenient and idiomatic way to express that.
So coming back to your question about DispatchQueue.main.async, I cannot think of any case where these should capture weak self. People apply it all the time, and IMO it's a mistake (though not a terrible one).
When DispatchQueue.async() is called on a global queue (including main), I expect the provided block to always be executed, and the target should be preserved long enough to ensure that happens. IMO adding extra machinery to allow the target to disappear in that fraction of a second is both wasteful and confusing. However, it is also very common and does not do a lot of harm.
There is an obscure case where scheduling a block that holds a weak reference on a DispatchQueue makes sense. If you have a custom queue that you suspend(), you may want objects to deallocate before you resume() the queue. The number of iOS developers who manage queues this way rounds to zero; I only bring it up for completeness. (I think the last time I called suspend() on a queue was before Swift came out.)

You are completely incorrect about the global queues and the main queue. The global queues are background concurrent queues and it is correct that items on them are likely to new executed very soon after being added. The main queue is the serial queue equivalent to the main thread.

The main queue is a serial queue that represents things done on the main UI thread. A task added to that may not execute for some time depending on what UI events are pending. It's absolutely possible, that a captured object for a closure on it might be gone. Incidentally, the same does apply for the global queue, it's just that the time scales are shorter.

By "I expect the provided block to always be executed," I mean "it is easier to reason about if it is allowed to execute," not "I am unaware of how ARC and GCD work." I am aware that it is possible for something to be released prior to being executed on a queue. I am saying that it is in most cases better to prevent the thing from being released by holding a strong rather than weak reference, and allowing the operation to run rather than creating short-lived race conditions that must be reasoned about (and that most people do not actually reason about).
